# how to use luma theme css class files in my frontend module

Tags: frontend, magento2

i am developing sample frontend modules in magento 2.using default luma theme.I want to know how to set luma css styles to my custom .phtml file.i mean where i can find these css class file

Answer (score 0):

Less files for specific theme and module should be placed in \app\design\frontend\\\_\web\css\source

This doc can be useful:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/debug-theme.html#debug-theme-style